# Under swift, do I need to import the security framework manually to use the keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, security.framework

I wanna save login credentials in my app using the iOS keychain under swift. I downloaded the [SwiftKeychainWrapper](https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper/blob/develop/SwiftKeychainWrapper/KeychainWrapper.swift) and watched a few [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YTlXk3Z36k). Following these I copied the KeychainWrapper.swift file to my project and started using the provided functions to store some strings.
Everything works fine but now I wonder about the need for the security framework which I didn't import manually. Is this something I still need to do in swift? I can Cmd+click those kSec keys in the wrapper and it sends me to the security framework - does this mean it's "built in" into swift now or something like that?

If I do need that framework why does it work right now "without" it? Are my strings saved but not encrypted or something like that?

I also checked out 1-2 other github projects about the keychain like [Locksmith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY-lQHJJ2zM) which doesn't seem to make me import that framework manually either.

Cheers

Comment: Xcode automatically links used system frameworks. There's a setting somewhere in the Xcode project file.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it completely. Does this mean I do have to make some setting at least or is that the default behaviour and I'm fine just using the SwiftKeychainWrapper.swift file?

Comment: Usually you don't need to do anything, just import it in your source file and you're good to go :)

Comment: Wait, "import in in your source file" - so I do need to import `import Security` somewhere?